# C2664 when casting child class to templated parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, casting, pointers

I have a parent class which is templated, and a child class which implements it.

`template< typename T1, typename T2>

class ParentClass{ . . . };`

`class ChildClass : public ParentClass<MyT1, MyT2> { . . . };`

And I want to have a pointer which I can use polymorphically:

`ParentClass<T1, T2>* ptr;

ptr = static_cast<ParentClass<MyT1, MyT2>* >(new ChildClass() );`

No matter how I cast it, I always get a C2664 which has the same expression:

error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ParentClass< T1,T2> *' to 'ParentClass< T1,T2> *'

Is it not possible to cast pointer types between inherited types if the parent is templated, even if the types specified in the templates are the same?

Comment: Is `MyT1` different from `T1`? The `static_cast` as written is inconsistent.

Comment: What compiler are you using? VC++?

Comment: Why do you have first `T1` and `MyT1`? Should the first one be `MyT1` instead?

Comment: Are you omitting a `with T1 = … , T2 = …` from the error message?

Comment: The cast you intend to do should be legal. The error code is specific to your compiler, it's not some standard error code. Anyway in your sample code you cast from `ParentClass<T1, T2>*` to `ParentClass<MyT1, MyT2>*` which is different. Are you sure that the error code is the one reported? You should try to give some code to reproduce your error. Most probably, trying to isolate the error you will come up with a solution yourself.

Answer (score 5):

C2664 is complaining about the assignment, not the cast (you would get error C2440, "'static_cast':  cannot convert from...," if the cast was invalid).

The problem is that the following are not the same:

```
ParentClass<T1, T2>*
ParentClass<MyT1, MyT2>*
```

Template instantiations with different parameters are different, unrelated types.

This should work fine:

```
ParentClass<MyT1, MyT2>* ptr;
ptr = static_cast<ParentClass<MyT1, MyT2>* >(new ChildClass() );
```

Though it is entirely unnecessary to cast in this case, since pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base conversions are implicit, so the following is all you need:

```
ptr = new ChildClass();
```

Comment: Template instantiations are actually the same, I just erroneously mixed up the two in the simple example code I typed above. T1 and T2 are the typenames from the class declaration, MyT1 and MyT2 are actual types. You're right, it should be: 

`ParentClass<MyT1, MyT2>* ptr;  
ptr = static_cast<ParentClass<MyT1, MyT2>* >(new ChildClass() );`

I tried simple assignment (implicit casting), typecasting, and static casting as experiments.

Comment: @DC:  You'll need to edit your question with the _exact_ code you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a static cast. Consider this code, which works as expected:

```
template <typename T>
struct base
{ virtual ~base(){} };

struct child : base<int>
{};

int main(void)
{
    base<int>* b = new child;
    // could be = static_cast<base<int>*>(new child);, but useless

    delete b;
}
```

Are you sure the base template parameters are the same?